# Where does “ö” fall in alphabetical ordering?

Tags: orthography, alphabet, diacritics, sort-ordering

Much to my surprise, I just learned that some English-language documents use the *ö* character. I need to know, when sorting words in an English-language document, where is *ö* placed?

- before *A*?
- after *Z* ?
- before *O* ?
- after *O* ?

Also, I am curious about whether there is a capital *ö*. If there is, then the justification for *ö* would not exclusively be to break diphthongs. Why else use *ö*?

Comment: I'm not sure about how English handles it, so I will not give this as an answer, but in German it's sorted as o or oe depending on whether it's a name or a word. I can never remember which is sorted as which. In Swedish and Finnish it's considered a separate letter that comes last in the alphabet. Danish and Norwegian do the same with their counterpart, ø.

Comment: This is dependent on the language.  In English, since there's no real "rule", it could be any of the above, something else, or the program sorting could upchuck and you'd see nothing.  If no provision was made otherwise then most likely the characters would be sorted based on their Unicode numeric values, after the standard alphabet and standard punctuation characters.

Comment: @Sixth Not entirely correct: the extra letters in the Scandinavian alphabets are ordered differently. Originally, there were just ä/æ and ö/ø; å came in later. In Swedish (and, by extension, Finnish), å was added before the others, so ö is last. In Danish and Norwegian, å was appended at the end, so there ø comes between æ and å. Neither Icelandic not Faroese have å, so ö and ø (respectively) are last there too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You are right about Danish and Norwegian. I remembered it as ä, å, ø, but now that you pointed it out, I realised I was wrong.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet As far as I can tell, the OED uses a collation that only considers diacritics after the base letter, which is what you are supposed to do in English. So for example, they order *Stocyen, stød, stoddy* and *resume, résumé, resumed*.

Comment: @tchrist Any idea how they order them internally? Would ö come before or after ó, for example?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I can actually check that if you can think of some pair where that is the only difference. So, unfortunately, I cannot check *Ragnarök* since only that form not *Ragnarøk(kr)* is listed.  But if you can come up with a pair, yes, I can check. Actually, any two words both with diacritics that are the same without diacritics but are different with them and whose diacritics differ would work. I can probably write a regex for that.

Comment: @tchrist Perhaps _Ångström_ and _à la_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In that case, *à la* appears BEFORE *Ångström* because the first letter is “the same” while the second letter has L coming before N.  One does not count non-letters like spaces or hyphens or dashes, either. I need a case where only the diacritic differs and not any letters if I am to try to figure out how they order diacritics themselves.

Comment: Hey, be happy you don't need to deal with digraphs. In Hungarian, "csekk" comes *after* "cvikker", because the letter 'cs' comes after the letter 'c', while 'cv' is just a consonant cluster, not a separately-defined letter.

Comment: @Marthaª Indeed! Hungarian even has a *DZS* trigraph to contend with, something not even Welsh (which also has digraphs) requires. We should also give thanks that the OP did not ask about where *Mc-* and *Mac-* surnames are expected to sort in English. :)

Comment: Or indeed the Celtic languages in general, where initial mutations are undone for alphabetising purposes, so that Welsh _wr_ is listed right before _gwraig_, and Irish _hatanna_ comes right before _atáirg_ when it means ‘swellings’, but right before _hearóin_ when it means ‘hats’…

Comment: Of course there is a capital-O-umlaut. Has nobody ever heard of [Mesut Özil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesut_%C3%96zil)?

Comment: You can always do the cheap and internationally consistent (?) and sort by ASCII code.

Comment: @Raphael No, sorting by bit does not produce an alphabetic sort: it produces an analphabetic sort.

Comment: My recall is the umlauts are in fact native English; however they don't mean what speakers of other European speakers expect them to mean. They mean one thing only, syllable break before this letter (breaks up what would be otherwise dipthongs or combined vowels) e.g. coöperate. And no, there is no capital: it becomes COOPERATE if uppercased.

Comment: @Joshua That’s not true: if the lowercase is *coöperate* then the uppercase is *COÖPERATE*. Similarly, the uppercase of *François* is *FRANÇOIS*, just as the uppercase of *El Niño* is *EL NIÑO*. Never strip diacritics when casemapping.

Comment: @tchrist Maybe point out that this rule, too, is language-specific.  In French, it is acceptable to strip diacritics when upcasing.  In languages where the diacritics create a distinct letter, such as for å ä ö in Swedish, it is of course totally unacceptable.  On the other hand, traditionally, Swedish treated W as just a variant of V, so they would sort as equivalent (with Westerstrand before Vårbäck but after Valdermarsson in the phone book, for example).

Comment: @tripleee: That's specific to which orthographical rules you use - in France and in Québec, the official way to write words requires the use of accents on upper-case letters, while in French-speaking Switzerland, the official guidelines say that accents should be *omitted* for initial upper-case letters of words otherwise written lower-case, according to [these descriptions](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_des_majuscules_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Accentuation_des_majuscules_et_des_capitales). Everyday use may well differ, though.

Comment: @Joshua - the thing that **looks** like an umlaut but has the function of separating the pronounciation of two adjacent vowels is in fact a **diaeresis** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29). Looks the same, but calling it an umlaut isn't technically correct. As you rightly say these are (or can be -- I believe they are all optional) used in native English spellings. They occur with `o`, `i` or `e`.

Comment: Figures. I normally have to look up the name; yet this time I took the poster's name to spare looking it up.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19381/discussion-on-question-by-davidge-where-does-o-fall-in-alphabetical-ordering).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Ignore diacritics when sorting English — except to break ties.

---

When sorting  English text  — but not the text of various other languages — one does not distinguish letters with and without diacritics as different ***unless*** tie-breaking is required because all letters are the same otherwise.   In such a case that two entries differ only by their diacritics — like with *resume* versus *résumé* — the one with diacritics ***follows*** the one without them.

This means that should an *Ö* occur in English text, it is to be treated just like a regular *O* unless there is also a version **without** the diacritic, as might occur with *coöperate* and *cooperate* or *co-operate*.  Those three all have the same letters in them as far as English is concerned, differing only in non-letters.

Note that only letters are supposed to be considered when sorting text. One ignores non-letters such as spaces, hyphens, dashes, or full stops, when sorting English text.  That means that the five imagined book-titles below are correctly sorted **as text** in this fashion:

> Little Red, More Blue
>       Little Red Mushrooms
>       Little, Red Rider
>       Little Red Riding Hood
>       Little Red Tent

Diacritics are rare in English words, occurring only in loanwords or words marked for poetic meter, as in *learnèd* or *Faërie*.  Being so rare in the first place, the ordering of different diacritics against each other (like *é* vs. *è* vs. *ê* vs. *ë*) may not be especially well defined in older dictionaries. The need for distinguishing those is rare enough that I haven’t yet found a single example of this in the OED.

In modern sorting of text, the default ordering of diacritics is provided by the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/)’s DUCET.  However, this is regularly modified under per-locale concerns.  English needs no tailoring because the default works just fine for us unaltered. But many other languages do.

For example, French, Spanish, and German phonebooks all have their overrides in this regard.  An English dictionary would place *piñata* before *Pinochet* . However, a Spanish dictionary would instead swap the order by listing *Pinochet* before *piñata*; this is because because unlike vowels with accent marks, *n* and *ñ* are considered completely separate letters in Spanish but not in English, collating in that order.

On the other hand, someone whose surname were *Föhn* in Germany would be expected to be found sorted as being exactly the same as people whose surnames were *Foehn* in the German phonebook, with forenames overriding ties.

Modern English has no such special needs apart from the unusual case of sorting people’s names, although words spelled with the typographic ligatures *æ* and *œ* must be treated as if spelled with two characters instead of one, so as though those were *ae* and *oe* respectively. That means that *Cæsar* sorts as though it were *Caesar* and *œuvre* as though it were *oeuvre*.

### Languages Beyond Modern English

That’s for Modern English. [Old English had its own alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_Latin_alphabet), which at least at one point was ordered this way:

> A, Æ, B, C, D, Ð, E, F, Ᵹ/G, H, I, L, M, N, O, P, R, S, T, Þ, U, Ƿ/W, X, Y

Notice how in Old English just like in today’s Icelandic, Æ was a real letter in its own right falling between A and B.  It was not just a typographic ligature as in *Cæsar*; it’s an actual lexical ligature, which means it’s its own letter, not just a typesetting matter.  So you really have to know the language of the text you are sorting to know what rules to apply: Modern English equates *æ* to *ae*, but Old English did not, while German phonebooks equate *ä* to *ae*.  Sorting can be hard if you let it be.

Sometimes questions arise about what to do with letters outside a normal alphabet, which in Old English could have arisen if there had been some Greek loanword in it with a K or a Z, or a word with an “and” symbol like & (the “et” scribal abbreviation) or ⁊ (the Tironian “et”, still used in Irish).

What to do here really depends on your goal in the collation. Analphabetics like numbers and punctuation do not count for dictionary/library sorts, but you still have to do something with them.  Otherwise you won’t get a deterministic result. Unicode does provide an ordering for these, which is normally consulted only when all alphabetics are the same and so the strings differ only in their analphabetics, but these do not necessarily “make sense” because there is no agreed-upon ordering for non-numeric analphabetics that everyone can just rattle off.

As for non-Latin letters, this really depends on what you are sorting. The OED, for example, transliterates the rare Greek letters that may appear in headwords into corresponding Latin ones for sorting purposes. That way *β-nornicotine* is sorted as though that Greek beta were spelled with a Latin B instead; it does not count as “beta”, just as “b”.

### Sorting of Names

Personal names are special in many languages, not just in German — and this includes English. The sorting of English books by the author’s name, for example, has a special rule for where to place surnames beginning with *Mc-* or *Mac-* ***when but only when*** those are patronymic prefixes.  They go after the L-authored books and before any other M-authored books, with *Mc* and *Mac* counting as identical. This is because you should not have to know which way somebody spelled it.

So for example, here are some hypothetical names sorted under this special “patronymic” rule:

> *Larry Ladd, Louis L’Amour, Douglas MacArthur,
>   Leonard McCoy,
>   Marty McFly,
>   Doug MacIlroy,
>   Ian McKellen,
>   Mitch Mabelle,
>   Philip Macedon,
>   David Macey,
>   Mary Magdalene.*

The problem with that is that you **do** have to distinguish the surnames that start with *Mc-* or *Mac-* because they were originally patronymic from the ones that do so by for other reasons that patronymics — which is why *Macedon* and *Macey* aren’t in the *Mc/Mac* set that follow L and precede M.  [See Wikipedia’s list of Scottish writers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Scottish_writers#M) for more 
examples of this peculiar name-sorting strategy.

## SEE ALSO

For how to sort text in various **non**-English languages, see also:

- the [Icelandic alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_orthography#Alphabet)
- the [Swedish alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_alphabet#Alphabet)
- the [Spanish alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_alphabet#The_Alphabet_in_Spanish)
- the [Welsh alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_alphabet)
- the [Irish alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_alphabet)
- the [Hungarian alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_alphabet)
- the [German alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography#Sorting)

Some of those languages count certain digraphs and trigraphs as single letters for alphabetic sorting.  An obvious case is that before the reforms of 1997, Spanish counted CH as its own letter after C and before D, causing *chocolate* to come after *color* not before it. Although this was “officially” altered for Spanish, many other languages still have digraphs (or worse) that are expected to sort as their own letters.

English, fortunately, has no such digraph issue the way say Welsh still does, and so sorting English text is mostly a straightforward affair.

Comment: About the only thing not covered in this great answer is sorting of characters outside of the A-Z alphabet, which has more variation—generally numbers and symbols before A and non-English letters after Z though with some collations having rules about the letters that were once used in English such as maybe Ð after D, but those rules differing in different collations, but this is less consistent than the stuff in this answer.

Comment: @JonHanna Fixed in the next release. :)

Comment: I think this all applies not to English text per se, but to text that is sorted for the benefit of an English-speaking audience. So if a list of book titles contains a Swedish title, you'd apply these rules as best as you can to the Swedish letters. And on the other hand, if Leonard McCoy moves to Germany, he should be sorted according to German rules in a German phone book.

Comment: As a slight completion: Apparently, in an *Austrian* phone book, the person named *Föhn* would expect to find themselves right *after* the last names that start with *Fo*, and *before* the first (hypothetical) name that starts with *Fp*, if any. The English WP article provides a [nice overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29#Printing_conventions_in_German).

Comment: An interesting case (I intentionally don't say "exception") is the Danish (and Norwegian) letter _Å_. This is a relatively new letter (as noted) and before its advent would be written _Aa_ in upper case and _aa_ in lower case. Note that the two letters _a_ and _a_ that it comprises are not independent letters. In modern Danish, the _Aa_ variant of _Å_ still exists (most often in names) and is treated just like _Å_. Hence, to find, for example, the town _Aarhus_ in a Danish atlas, go all the way to the back! (The spelling _Århus_ is, strangely enough, deprecated - although still seen.)

Comment: It's worth noting too that in Swedish sorting, sometimes V and W are considered the same letter and sometimes they are considered different (sorted in that order). Now, W is not often used in Swedish so this isn't a big problem in practice.

Comment: @dynamo Whether you write _Aarhus_ or _Århus_ is mostly a matter of politics these days, outside purely formalised contexts. Either way, though, you're more likely to be keelhauled for calling it a ‘town’ instead of a city. ;-)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608664/2085).

Answer (score 4):

When you use Microsoft Word's alphabetize tool, it treats the "ö" as if it were just a regular "o." This seems to match the treatment of other accented letters not typically used in English. For example, *piñata* retains its "ñ" because it is taken directly from Spanish, but when alphabetized in English, the "ñ" is treated as a regular "n."

Comment: In English, yes; in Spanish, no: *piñata* comes after *pino*, not before it, under Spanish collation.

Comment: Well, yes, but we're talking about alphabetization in English-language documents.

Comment: But if you rely on the computer to solve it for you, there needs to be somebody who understands this stuff to make the computer do the right thing in the first place, and not just for English (like often it was in the dark ages).

Comment: By the way, this is not true of computers in general - they usually sort by ASCII code so accented characters come later (example: a e o á â é ê ó ô ö).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat ASCII has no accented letters. Unicode does though.

Comment: @tchrist actually they are part of "Extended ASCII".

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat. I don't think that "Extended ASCII" is really a thing. It's a general catch-all term for 8-bit encodings where the first half is ASCII, but there are loads of those.